# Type C cutoff switch

Tags: circuit-design, usb, relay, usb-c

This is my first electrical engineering project and I have no experience or formal training.

I have a very specific problem that led me down this rabbit hole.  To make the very long story short: I need disconnect a Type C USB cable without physically removing or manually interacting with it. I succeeded using a PCB to connect to cables and breakout the C pins to a 12v relay.  When power is supplied to the relay the CC pins are connected and both devices work as intended.  When power is cut both devices assume there is no cable.  My only problem is the bulk of my design.  Relays are big.  Is there another way I could accomplish this with smaller components?  I considered an optocoupler, but I'm worried the emitter and collector only flow in one direction. I considered a USB IC, but the complexity is overwhelming.  I exhausted software options between the devices.

I've attached my current design.  (switch and signal represent the 12v circuit and is intentionally interchangeable)
[image]

Comment: You can buy CMOS switches to use instead of relays. What's the resistance tolerance on the connection on the CCx lines? There are switches available with very low resistances. Take care that fast switching can break USB detect/release protocols that assume delays characteristic of a human plugging and unplugging them (been there, done that, burnt the T-shirt!)

Comment: You can get reed relays that are the size and shape of a 14 pin DIP IC.

Comment: Type C can handle 10 and 20 Gbps . But any switches you are using or being suggested cannot. This demands transmission line theory for controlled impedances with Current  Mode switching..

Comment: If you want to see a commercial solution USB 3.0 Switch, Viagkiki USB Switch Selector 2 Computers Sharing 4 USB Devices KVM Switcher for PC, Printer, Scanner, Mouse, Keyboard with 2 Pack USB Cable

Comment: But to disable a USB channel, any imbalance on the channel will functionally disable high speed data. but if you are just charging, that must be specified in question.